# jQuery Hiding element based on previous row td value

Tags: jquery

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="/payinvoice/1">Pay Invoice 1</a>
            <span class="paid hidden">False</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="/payinvoice/2">Pay Invoice 2</a>
            <span class="paid hidden">False</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and I need to hide the Pay Invoice 2 link if the value of the span in the previous row td is False.

I came up with this:

```
$('span.paid').each(function () {
    if ($(this).prev("span.paid").text() == "False") {            
        $(this).prev("a").addClass("hidden");
    }
});
```

but it doesn't work. Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('span.paid').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($.trim($this.closest('tr').prev('tr').find('span.paid').text()) == 'False') {            
        $this.prev('a').addClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

Comment: @Purmou Yes… As OP said, “I need to hide the Pay Invoice 2 link if the `value` of the `span` in the previous row `td` is `'False'`.” That’s exactly what this snippet does.

Comment: Heh, I missed the `prev('tr')`. My mistake!

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/heZuv/1/)'s what you're looking for:

```
$('span.paid').each(function () {
    var prev = $(this).parents('tr').prev().find('span.paid').text();
    if (prev=='False') {            
        $(this).prev().hide();
    }
});
```

Firstly, we're setting the text to the `prev` variable for organization purposes.

We first find the `tr` element that holds the `span.paid` the function is being applied to and selecting the previous `tr`. We search for `span.paid` in that `tr`, get its text, and match it to the string `'False'` in the `if()` function.

Big explanation, but simple results.

Comment: This will break if you modify the markup later, e.g. to add a wrapper `<span>` element around the text. Don’t use `.parent().parent()` etc., use `.closest()` (like in my answer).

Comment: @MathiasBynens: Modified...now it uses `parents()` which selects the entire parent tree for an element.

Comment: Why use `parents()` if you’re gonna use `.text()` anyway? `.text()` will only get the text of the first element in the collection. Use `.closest()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $('span.paid').each(function () {
      if ($(this).parents('tr').prev().find("span.paid").text() === "False") {            
          $(this).prev("a").addClass("hidden");
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code,

```
$('tr').each(function() {
    if ($("span.paid", $(this)).text() == "False") {
        $("a", $(this).next('tr')).addClass("hidden");
    }
});
```

[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/RpjDG/)

Comment: @Purmou:nop it is not hiding whole `tr`. it just hiding the specific `a` tag.

Comment: Check your jsfiddle. It hides the entire next `tr`.

Comment: @Purmou: it is hiding only next row `a` tag. but in his markup, he already added `hidden` class for those spans. that why you see it as hiding entire row. but it is not hiding entire row. if you want you can inspect and see the code. :) see updated version of your sample http://jsfiddle.net/heZuv/2/, same behavior.